# Is it possible to set attribute value through .send?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can I do something like this?

```
self.send(:twitter_url) = result
```

It doesn't work like this for me.

```
self.send(:twitter_url, result) # this doesn't work either
```

`Model.twitter_url` is an attribute (string column)

I need this for refactoring.

---

Ok, here's one more thing:

```
argument = :twitter_url
self.send(argument=, result)
```

What should I do here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `twitter_url=` "setter" method, so this should work:

```
send(:twitter_url=, result)
```

About your edit, you can do at least two things:

First approach:

```
send("#{argument}=", result)
```

second approach, using `write_attribute`:

```
write_attribute(argument, result)
```

Comment: using send is safe?

Answer (score 4):

For a Rails (ActiveRecord) model you can set an attribute via [`write_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Write.html#method-i-write_attribute):

```
write_attribute(:twitter_url, result)
```

or the shorthand [`[]=`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D):

```
self[:twitter_url] = result
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to repeat the other guys' answers, but just want to point out a difference between `myobj.send("methodname=", value)` and `myobj[:methodname] = value`.

The second one bypasses the usual setter method, which can do extra "stuff", ie have extra functionality besides just setting the value.  For example, with postcodes you might, for search or optimisation reasons, have another field which removes spaces and upcases the postcode, like this

```
#in User, who has name, address1, address2, postcode, tidied_postcode
def postcode=(pcode)
  self[:postcode] = pcode #the usual content of a setter like this
  self[:tidied_postcode] = pcode.gsub(" ","").upcase #some extra functionality
end
```

With this situation, if you were to do either of the following, `tidied_postcode` **would** get updated too.

```
@user.postcode = "abc 123"
@user.send("postcode=", "abc 123")
```

Whereas with these, `tidied_postcode` **would not** get updated.

```
@user[:postcode] = "abc 123"
@user.write_attribute(:postcode, "abc 123")
```

I just mention this in case it's informative.